# Does AngularJS redraw DOM when scope updates w/ equivalent data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm working on optimizing the performance of my AngularJS app. 
Let's say I call a service that returns an object, which is tied to the scope. If I call that service again and it returns the same data, will the DOM tied to the scope redraw itself with the same data? Does it make sense to check for equivalency in the service return to avoid redrawing the DOM?

Comment: you can test it using a lot of fake data (something that you can notice), for what i understand angular doesnt analize changes on the structure as other frameworks

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide Scope Watch Performance Considerations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-performance-considerations). AngularJS Achiles Heel is its watch strategy. Avoid changing object references on scope. Instead change the properties of existing references.

Comment: Ran some tests, can confirm that performance is negatively affected (app is running in Cordova so resources are limited). Temp solution is to update only the difference between scope data and returned data (I'm using https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff)